# Resource ServletContext resource does not exist

Tags: spring-boot, xsd, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I'm working on a project (spring boot) and I have to convert xml file to Java classes using the maven jaxb2 plugin. I'm following this link:
the classes are generated the problem is when I try to unmarshall the xml I had this error:
Resource ServletContext resource [/xsd/MX_seev_031_001_05. xsd] does not exist 
this is my application.properties:

```
context.path =xml.swift.spring.com
schema.location= xsd/MX_seev_031_001_05.xsd
```

this my bean of config:

```
@Bean
public Jaxb2Marshaller createJaxb2Marshaller(@Value("${context.path}") final String contextPath,
        @Value("${schema.location}") final Resource schemaResource){

    Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    marshaller.setContextPath(contextPath);
    marshaller.setSchema(schemaResource);


    Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
    properties.put(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    marshaller.setMarshallerProperties(properties);

    return marshaller;
```

the xsd file is under src/main/resources/xsd and this is my pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
<version>0.12.1</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>add-source-for-demoapp</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>generate</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd</schemaDirectory>
            <schemaIncludes>
                <include>*.xsd</include>
            </schemaIncludes>


            <!--  Other configuration options-->

        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

what i'am missing?

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had basically the same issue, when I started to use spring-boot-starter-data-rest in addition to spring-oxm (I also have spring-boot-starter-data-jpa) in my pom.xml.

The problem is with your 2nd auto injected argument;
@Value("${schema.location}") final Resource schemaResource

So instead of

```
@Bean
public Jaxb2Marshaller createJaxb2Marshaller(@Value("${context.path}") final String contextPath, @Value("${schema.location}") final Resource schemaResource){
    //...
    marshaller.setSchema(schemaResource);
    //...
}
```

Do below;

```
@Bean
public Jaxb2Marshaller createJaxb2Marshaller(@Value("${context.path}") final String contextPath, @Value("${schema.location}") final String schemaLocation){
    //...
    Resource schemaResource = new ClassPathResource(schemaLocation);
    marshaller.setSchema(schemaResource);
    //...
}
```

Give it a try, it will work.